# Tablelayout: how to fix it?

Tags: android, tablelayout

I m trying to create a tableLayout.

My problem is that my table content doesn't fit in the screen.

This is my result:

[image]

as you can see the last row is cut..How can i fix it?This is my code of xml:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_weight="3"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <!-- grammi stoixeiwn pinaka -->

            <TableRow >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Αριθμός"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Όνομα"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="|"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Διαδρομή"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="|"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Μέτρα"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="|"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="Παρατηρήσεις"
                    android:textColor="#e5e975"
                    android:textSize="8px" />
            </TableRow>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" />

            <!-- TableRow 1 -->

            <TableRow >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt1a"
                    android:layout_column="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"                     android:text="1"

                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2a"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"                     android:text="Όνομα"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt3a"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"                     android:text="|"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt4a"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"                    android:text="Όνομα"

                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt5a"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"                    android:text="|"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt6a"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"                    android:text="Όνομα"

                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt7a"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"                    android:text="|"

                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="8px" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt8a"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"                    android:text="Όνομα"

                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="8px" />
            </TableRow>
//more table rows here


</TableLayout></ScrollView>
```

EDIT:

I want to make i t look like:

[image]

Comment: Is it because its in a scroll view?

Comment: Do you want to strechcolumn '1'? If not, why can't you change strechcolumn to '4'?

Comment: in column 4 i may have more than 30 characters in each row,so i would like to continue below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` on the TextView in the last column.

Comment: I tried your code in the Eclipse WYSIWYG editor and it looks like removing `android:layout_gravity="left"` from the first textView solves the problem.

Comment: thanks for your time.That is working,but i still have text only in one line,so if i have more characters i cant see them in two or more lines..

Answer (score 0):

You may try two things, 1) Change stretch column from '1' to '4' 2) Mark 4th column as shrinkable using `android:shrinkColumns = "4"`